# Copy field to another field in same module - suitecrm

Tags: php, sugarcrm, suitecrm

When creating a new record i am trying to copy the value from a relate field to the name field of my custom module. To do this i am using the following logic_hook:

```
<?php
// Do not store anything in this file that is not part of the array or the hook version. This file will
// be automatically rebuilt in the future.
$hook_version = 1;
$hook_array = Array();
// position, file, function
$hook_array['before_save'] = Array(); 
$hook_array['before_save'][] = Array(1, 'Value from one field to another', 'custom/modules/chan_channelpartner/textcopy.php', 'textcopy','textcopy');

?>
```

and here is my textcopy.php file:

```
<?php
    if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

    class textcopy
    {
        function textcopy($bean, $event, $arguments)
        {
            $bean->name = $bean->namenew_c;
        }
}  

?>
```

When running this file my browser returns a white screen with the following text:

```
name = $bean->namenew_c; } } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your **Apache/PHP** logs for errors. Something should pop up there.

Comment: The only error i can find relating to this issue is: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'textcopy' not found in /home/cloudtr1/public_html/include/utils/LogicHook.php on line 238
That Line refers to the following code: $class = new $hook_class($this->bean, $event, $arguments);

Comment: The output that you are seeing on the screen is completely throwing me off. Maybe there is an encoding issue in that file or some weird PHP setup issue. It's breaking right after or at $bean->

Comment: Excellent! That was exactly the issue. I had my notepad++ set to encode in USC-2 LE. I have changed this and the code now works. Thanks for your help